# Convert date variable, in the form "JA11" to date in Stata

Tags: date, stata

I have a data set that that has a date variable that is now in the form of a two digit alphabetic abbreviation for the month followed by the two digit numerical year, such as JA11 for January 2011. How can I convert this to something Stata can recognize as a month/year date?

Data Structure example:

. list id1 ins HPR if _n<20

```
    +--------------------+
    | id1    ins     HPR |
    |--------------------|
 1. |   1   AP11   1 YES |
 2. |   1   AU11   1 YES |
 3. |   1   DE11   1 YES |
 4. |   1   FE11   1 YES |
 5. |   1   JA11   1 YES |
    |--------------------|
 6. |   1   JL11   1 YES |
 7. |   1   JU11   1 YES |
 8. |   1   MA11   1 YES |
 9. |   1   MY11   1 YES |
10. |   1   NO11   1 YES |
    |--------------------|
11. |   1   OC11   1 YES |
12. |   1   SE11   1 YES |
13. |   2   AP11    2 NO |
14. |   2   AU11    2 NO |
15. |   2   DE11    2 NO |
    |--------------------|
16. |   2   FE11    2 NO |
17. |   2   JA11    2 NO |
18. |   2   JL11    2 NO |
19. |   2   JU11    2 NO |
    +--------------------+
```

.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated for your sample data:**

```
gen month=substr(hp,1,2)
gen year=substr(hp,3,4)
replace year="2011" if year=="11" **you can omit this in your real data
```

---

This part is not required for the data you provide. But you can use in real data

```
local yr "03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11"
local newyr "2003 2004 2004 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011"
local n: word count `yr'
forvalues i=1/`n'{
local yr`i' : word `i' of `yr'
local newyr`i' : word `i' of `newyr'
bys ids: replace year="`newyr`i''" if year=="`yr`i''"
local i=`i'+1
}
```

---

```
local mon "JA FE MA AP MY JU JL AU SE OC NO DE"
local newmon "JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC"
local n: word count `mon'

forvalues i=1/`n'{
local mon`i' : word `i' of `mon'
local newmon`i' : word `i' of `newmon'
bys ids: replace month="`newmon`i''" if month=="`mon`i''"
local i=`i'+1
}

egen datevar=concat(month year),punct(" ")
generate datevar1=date(datevar,"MY")
format datevar1 %d


ids hp  month   year    datevar datevar1
1   AP11    APR 2011    APR 2011    01apr2011
1   AU11    AUG 2011    AUG 2011    01aug2011
1   DE11    DEC 2011    DEC 2011    01dec2011
1   FE11    FEB 2011    FEB 2011    01feb2011
1   JA11    JAN 2011    JAN 2011    01jan2011
1   JL11    JUL 2011    JUL 2011    01jul2011
1   JU11    JUN 2011    JUN 2011    01jun2011
1   MA11    MAR 2011    MAR 2011    01mar2011
1   MY11    MAY 2011    MAY 2011    01may2011
1   NO11    NOV 2011    NOV 2011    01nov2011
1   OC11    OCT 2011    OCT 2011    01oct2011
1   SE11    SEP 2011    SEP 2011    01sep2011
2   AP11    APR 2011    APR 2011    01apr2011
2   AU11    AUG 2011    AUG 2011    01aug2011
2   DE11    DEC 2011    DEC 2011    01dec2011
2   FE11    FEB 2011    FEB 2011    01feb2011
2   JA11    JAN 2011    JAN 2011    01jan2011
2   JL11    JUL 2011    JUL 2011    01jul2011
2   JU11    JUN 2011    JUN 2011    01jun2011
```

Comment: If "MA" is March, what is May? What are June and July?

Comment: @ Nick: Exactly; that's why I provided the sample data with only first 3 months.

Comment: Quite; I should really be emphasising that OP should show the real rules.

Comment: @ Metrics: Thanks for the help. subtra and then replace will work for me. And that'a a good point on the abbreviations. I didn't realize that it's not just the first two letters. So March is MA and May is MY. June is JU and July is JL. On the data structure, I have person IDs and for each month/year with a dummy indicator for whether they meet a criteria during that month/year (long form). I have 2003 to 2011 data and each month of each year for many person IDs. But what you gave me will be a great help. Thanks to both.

Comment: So, the above methodology works; you can make code shorter by writing loops. If you provide the sample data, I can update my code with that.

Comment: Great. I added a simplified version of the variables of interest to my OP. Was that what you were looking for? I can add more or refine it if it would help. Thanks.

Comment: Please see my updated solution using the loop for month. You can repeat the same for years if you want.

Answer (score 2):

The date() function can convert virtually any date format into elapsed dates, which is the format Stata uses to manipulate date information. Elapsed dates are calculated as the number of days from January 1, 1960. This format is useful for adding or subtracting dates and changing the format of date variables.

```
 . tostring datevar, replace format(%20.0f)
 datevar was float now str8

 . replace datevar = "0" + datevar if length(datevar) == 7
 (2 real changes made)

 . list

      +----------+
      |  datevar |
      |----------|
   1. | 12031999 |
   2. | 02081998 |
   3. | 04071997 |
      +----------+

 . gen edatevar = date(datevar,"MDY")

 . format edatevar %td

 . list

      +----------------------+
      |  datevar    edatevar |
      |----------------------|
   1. | 12031999   03dec1999 |
   2. | 02081998   08feb1998 |
   3. | 04071997   07apr1997 |
      +----------------------+
```

For more information go to: 
http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/handling-date-information/